# SQL Server 2012 CPU usage spikes to 100%

Tags: sql-server-2012, java, aws, hibernate

I am using `SQL Server 2014 in AWS` and the AWS image configuration is 4 cores and 16GB RAM(`m3.xlarge`). I am running the following simple query,

```
SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE user_id = '10'
```

`user_table` contains 1000k records, `user_id` is primary key. When the above simple query is executed from my application through EJB hibernate, the CPU spikes to 10% for a moment and again it backs to normal.

So my use case is, 100 users will concurrently try to hit the application, so in a fraction of second 100 times the above query will try to execute in a fraction of second. So the CPU usage spikes to 100%. Once all the query execution is completed the CPU usage is back to normal at 1%.

- Why it so? whether I need to increase my AWS instance type?
- What should I have to do in-order to make SQL server to handle 100 or more concurrent hits without making high CPU usage? If my query is so complex then there might have a chance to get spike but my query is simple and straight forward.
- Is there is any bench mark metrics available for SQL server 2014?
- Any solution to make support for concurrent hits with SQL server by low CPU usage consumption?
- One more information my data file size is around `32.2GB` and log
  file size is around `894mb` for my database.
- My DB has the isolation level of `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is set to ON`.
  But when I tried by setting `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT to OFF`, there is a difference of 20% performance improvement but not that much considerable performance improvements.
- Similarly I faced another issue I posted over **here**. Consider this too for analysis(Some hint may arise from the question in the link).

Comment: There are a lots of dmvs that can tell you more about the current state of your server.One of it is : SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188743.aspx 
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/

Comment: Is your application server using database pooling? I would guess that the CPU spike is the application pool logging on to the server. You can check this by starting a perfmon trace and checking the 
Object: - SQLServer:General Statistics - Counter: - Logins/sec
Object: - SQLServer:General Statistics - Counter: - Logouts/sec

Comment: I couldn't able to get you. Can you please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

What is the *exact* type of the `user_id` column?

It is very likely not a `VARCHAR` column therefore the rules of [data type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) dictate that the comparison must be done by casting the `user_id` to the type of the `'10'` literal, thus negating the possibility of an index seek and forcing a full scan. This is a very common mistake.

I recommend reading [How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx) (do a mental translation for Java - Hibernate) and [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).